# what is the procedure of ubuntu Installation in a new laptop

Tags: laptop, compaq

i want to install ubuntu in my new laptop 1st time.so,i request you to kindly tell the proceedure to install in a free dos laptop for 1 st time

Answer (score 1):

Please allow me to help you.

As Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is the latest Ubuntu addition. I'm expecting that is the version you are trying to install.

Following [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) will help you (with screenshot) to install Ubuntu in your new laptop.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

If you need an idea to create a bootable Ubuntu installer USB, refer [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Please let us know if you face any challenge while doing that.